# Python List iteration list of list

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to iterate through a list of lists but not in the typical way such that I go through each element in the list of lists  then move to the next list.

How does the logic work if I wanted to print the elements in the order `1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6`, which is the list of lists element then the lists and repeat, instead of `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`?

```
ls = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Does /questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the lists are the same length:

```py
list_length = len(ls[0])
for i in range(list_length):
    for list in ls:
        print(list[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want short code

```
ls = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
result = [v for tt in list(zip(*tuple([tuple(x) for x in ls]))) for v in tt]
print(result)
```

Output

```
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

As suggested by @iz_, there's a shorter way for the same output

```
ls = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
result = [v for tt in zip(*ls) for v in tt]
print(result)
```

Comment: Why not just `[v for tt in zip(*ls) for v in tt]`?

Answer (score 1):

Transform your list of lists into a transposed flat list (technically, a tuple, but it makes no difference). `zip` transposes the list, `sum` flattens it.

```
indexes = sum(zip(*ls), tuple())
# (1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6)
```

If you still want a list (and perhaps you do not), call `list(indexes)`.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a library function defined for this : `itertools.zip_longest()`:

```
import itertools

zipped_list = itertools.zip_longest(*ls, fillvalue='-')
```

This is more generic since it will automatically create items even if you have more than 2 sublists.

On top of that, it also takes care of sublists with different lengths

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

ls = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]
print(ls)
res1 = [ls[r][c] for c in range(len(ls[0])) for r in range(len(ls)) ]
print(res1)

print('-' * 30)
# Now using numpy which is generally faster
np_ls = np.array(ls)
print(np_ls)
res = [j  for i in range(len(np_ls[0])) for j in np_ls[...,i]]
print(res)
```